# Where this solution of $f ' (x) = g(x)$ comes from?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I would have liked to solve the following first-order linear ODE for $f(x)$:
$$ f'(x) = g(x) $$

I attempted to solve it like this:
$$ \int f'(x)\,dx = \int g(x)\,dx $$
$$ f(x) = \int g(x)\,dx+C $$

Then I gave $ f'(x) = g(x) $ to WolframAlpha and its solution was quite surprising to me:
$$ f(x) = c_1+\int_1^{x} g(\xi)\,d\xi $$

I then actually paid for WolframAlpha|PRO to see the step-by-step solution, but it shows exactly the attempt and solution of mine...

[image: Step-by-step solution by WolframAlpha|PRO]

So my question is where do the *definite integral* and *xi* come from? What is the trick here I'm unaware of?
Knowing this would help me understand the exact solution of the quasispecies equation.

Comment: This is for functions that do not have an antiderivative that can be expressed in terms of elementary functions, so you can calculate the integral till a given value of $x$ using numerical methods, but might not be able to express $\int g(x)$ as a function, but rather as a number. The constant is probably to quantify the boundary values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the initial value. In this case, Wolfram Alpha chooses $1$ as initial "time" and you have
$$
y(x) = y(1)+\int_1^x g(t)\, dt, \quad c_1 = y(1),
$$
because of the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus). Apparently Wolfram uses the name "$\xi$" for the integral variable.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between

$$\int f'(x)\,dx+c=f(x)+c$$ and $$\int_a^x f'(t)\,dt+c=f(x)-f(a)+c.$$

Both describe *some* antiderivative of $f'$, with an indeterminate constant.

---

Note that you can also solve the ODEs with definite integrals:

$$f'(x)=g(x)\iff\int_{f_0}^fdf=\int_0^x g(t)\,dt\iff f(x)-f_0=g(x)-g(0).$$